# how to remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin angular application while Getting Data?

Tags: angularjs

After payment gateway success it redirect to http://localhost/august1stZustshop/#/home.In response headers i got information data,status accurately.

```
But Using $https it makes XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://secure.payu.in/_payment.
No 'Access-   Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.Origin 
'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

  $http({
        url: "https://secure.payu.in/_payment",
        method: "GET",
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data)
         console.log(status)
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
            console.log(status)
            console.log(data)
        })
```

Please tell me how to get the response headers data or how to remove cors error.

Comment: Since javascript doesn't allow cross origin ajax calls, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is the CORS way of enabling it.
When an ajax request is made, if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set in the response and the value of that header key matched the domain name your application is running, it shall allow cross domain ajax calls
This might help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
p.s - The header is set from the server side.

Comment: CORS is a security measure, you can't "remove" it from the client.  The server you are trying to access would need to allow you access, which also generally means you only access the API from a live site, not from your local development machine (i.e. you can't usually use localhost for secure APIs).